# GWT: How do I populate an initial list for a CellTree using an AsyncDataModel?

Tags: java, gwt

I'm using GWT 2.4.  I want to create a tree with a fixed set of top level nodes but upon opening each, the data is dynamically retrieved from the server.  I have found the AsyncDataProvider class to help me, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to pre-populate the data model with an initial set of values.  I have this code (not working) ...

```
public class CellTreeExample implements EntryPoint {

  /**
   * The model that defines the nodes in the tree.
   */
  private static class CustomTreeModel implements TreeViewModel {

    /**
     * Get the {@link NodeInfo} that provides the children of the specified
     * value.
     */
    public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(T value) {
      /*
       * Create some data in a data provider. Use the parent value as a prefix
       * for the next level.
       */
      AsyncDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<String>() { 
          @Override
          protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<String> display) {
            // Execute dynamic logic here.
      }
      };

      // Set a default set of nodes.
      TextCell textCell = new TextCell();
      final CellList<String> cellList = new CellList<String>(textCell);
      final List<String> rootNodes = getRootNodes();
      cellList.setRowCount(rootNodes.size(), true);
      dataProvider.addDataDisplay(cellList);

      // Return a node info that pairs the data with a cell.
      return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, new TextCell());
    }

    public boolean isLeaf(Object value) {
        // some logic
    }
  }

  public void onModuleLoad() {
    // Create a model for the tree.
    TreeViewModel model = new CustomTreeModel();

    /*
     * Create the tree using the model. We specify the default value of the
     * hidden root node as "Item 1".
     */
    CellTree tree = new CellTree(model, "Item 1");

    // Add the tree to the root layout panel.
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(tree);
  }
```

Nothing appears when I launch my application and I've confirmed that the initial cell list contains 6 items.  Any ideas why they are not displaying?  Is TextCell not the right type to use when constructing a CellList meant for a CellTree? - Dave

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CellTree via CellTreeNodeView calls setDataDisplay on the returned NodeInfo object with a self created NodeCellList instance, so it looks like it overrides your own CellList and that one never used.

Instead of creating a CellList that displays the values you should return a dataprovider that returns the initial values. I don't fully understand how you use the initial set, just as a placeholder or as the set of root nodes, so I'm not sure how your implemenation would look like, but you might take a look at the GWT CellTree showcase: http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellTree, especially look at the source code of the ContactTreeViewModel class.

Comment: I want the initial set to be pre-defined root nodes but then everything after that should be asynchronously (dynamically) loaded.  In the example you list, I can't figure out how things are being dynamically loaded.  It seems like all data is static.  Thanks for any other thoughts, - Dave

Comment: In the example in getNodeInfo is a check if value == null, this is the the root, in the else part of that if return the DefaultNodeInfo with your AsyncDataProvider instance. Your onRangeChanged should call updateRowData with dynamically retrieved data.

Answer (score 3):

```
// summarizing pseudocode
public <T> NodeInfo<?> getNodeInfo(final T value) {
  if(value == null) {  // root, return static list of top level nodes
    return new DefaultNodeInfo<String<( 
        new ListDataProvider<String>(Arrays.<String>asList("node1", "node2" ... ));
        , new TextCell());
  }
  else {
    AsyncDataProvider<String> dataProvider = new AsyncDataProvider<String>() { 
      @Override
      protected void onRangeChanged(HasData<String> display) {
        // Execute dynamic logic here - and fetch data from server or wherever
        // call updateRowData() in when data is available
        updateRowData(display.getVisibleRange(), /* List<String> results */);
      }
    }  

    return new DefaultNodeInfo<String>(dataProvider, new TextCell());
  }
}
```